# Java - store elements of ArrayList into separate blocks

Tags: java, arraylist, block, bufferedreader, filereader

so here is ALL of my code, which, in summary, standardises two text files then prints out the result.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Plagiarism {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Plagiarism myPlag = new Plagiarism();

        if  (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: No files input");
        }
        else if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (args[i]));
                    List<String> foo = simplify(reader);
                        for (int j = 0; j < foo.size(); j++) {
                            System.out.print(foo.get(j));
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println ("Error reading from file");
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> simplify(BufferedReader input) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            myList.add(line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","").toLowerCase().trim());
        }
        return myList;  
    }

}
```

The next bit I want to implement is this: Using the command line, the 3rd argument will be any integer(size of blocks) which the user enters. I have to use this then to store the elements of that array into separate blocks which overlap. EG: The cat sat on the mat, block size 4. Block 1 would be: Thec Block 2: heca Block 3: ecat, and so on, until it reaches the end of the array.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the block size use this :

```
if(args.length != 4)
    return;
int blockSize = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);
```

This an example that could help you

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "The dog is in the house";
    line = line.replace(" ", "");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= line.length() - 4; i++) 
        list.add(line.substring(i, i + 4));
    System.out.println(list);
```

}

output :

```
[Thed, hedo, edog, dogi, ogis, gisi, isin, sint, inth, nthe, theh, heho, ehou, hous, ouse]
```

Is that what you want to do

Comment: sure it's args[2], seeing as that is the third argument in the cmd?

Comment: when you call you program like this : myProgram arg1 arg2 arg3, the args array will conatin : args[0] = myProgram, args[1] = arg1, args[2] = arg2, args[3] = arg3.

Comment: Ah ok. Also, I'm using ArrayLists so i get an error when i try to use substring()

Comment: what's error you get? I have forgotten a parenthesis is that the error you get?

Comment: no, cant find symbol substring because im using list<string>

Comment: I have edited my answer and test it and it's work. If it doesn't work for you paste all the error you get.

Comment: @user3364788 EDIT: Sorry didnt see update before you posted. Yes that is what I want but if you look at my code it's an ArrayList that's already been standardised. Please look at my code first then reply back, thanks for your help though what you've done is what i want just in a different format

Comment: replace System.err.println ("Error reading from file"); with e.printStackTrace(); to know what's the exception you got. You must specfic exception.

Comment: Before adding this code let me just say it all worked. I get a nullpointerexception at this line. list.add(line.substring(k, k+blockSize));

Comment: Also I am not using Strings with this I am using ArrayList.

Comment: Ok, now it's doing it but has loads of random commas in the blocks?

Comment: What's? Can you please add the result you get and the content of the files you test with?

Answer (score 1):

WE can code it in mulitple ways, here is one example.

Input 3 arguments first 2 are files and 3rd one is the block size:

File1 contain: this is a boy

File2 contain: this is a girl

block size: 4

Expected Output:

this hisi isis sisa isab sabo aboy boyt oyth ythi this hisi isis sisa isag sagi agir girl

Program:

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Plagiarism {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Plagiarism myPlag = new Plagiarism();

    /*args = new String[3];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the 1st file path");
    args[0] = s.next();
     System.out.println("Enter the 2nd file path");
     args[1] = s.next();
     System.out.println("Enter size of block");
     args[2] = s.next();*/

    int blockSize = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);

    StringBuilder wholeContent = new StringBuilder("");


    if  (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: No files input");
    }
    else if (args.length > 0) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length-1; i++) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (args[i]));
                List<String> foo = simplify(reader);                   
                    for (int j = 0; j < foo.size(); j++) {
                        //System.out.print(foo.get(j));
                        wholeContent.append(foo.get(j));

                    }
            }


            System.out.println("The content of Line is = "+ wholeContent);
            System.out.println("The content of line based on the block size = "+ blockSize + " is:");
            for(int j=0; j<=(wholeContent.length()-blockSize); j++){
                            System.out.print(wholeContent.substring(j, j+4));
                            System.out.print(" ");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println ("Error reading from file");
        }
    }
}

public static List<String> simplify(BufferedReader input) throws IOException {
    String line = null;
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!" ".equals(line))
        myList.add(line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","").toLowerCase().trim());
    }
    return myList;  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All you are asking to do can be done with string manipulation. First use replaceAll() to remove your spaces, then use a for loop and substring() to create your blocks.

for your for loop you need to modify it so that it reads the two texts, then uses the 3rd argument as the block size so you would change your for loop from:

```
for(int i = 0; i<args.length;i++)
```

to:

```
for(int i = 1; i<3; i++)
```

this reads the first two arguments but not the third

Comment: I realise this, but struggling how to use the command line argument with this that specifies the block size?

Comment: well what does your command line argument look like at the moment?

Comment: java Plagiarism (text file) (text file) (block argument would be here)

Comment: ok, so whats the issue, you could just say java Plagiarism text1.txt text2.txt 5 and that should work

Comment: the first arguments is the program name. So the loop should start on i = 1